# GET form in Scala templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm attempting to create a form using GET to search given some input:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="@routes.Index.search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="search-field">Search:</label>
        <input id="search-field" class="form-control" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Sun"/>         </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Where the `Index` controller has the following method:

```
def search(q: String) = Action.async {
    ...
}
```

And my `routes` file has the following route:

```
GET        /search              controllers.Index.search(q: String)
```

I was expecting that this should work as I expect, which is that a `GET` request should be made to `http://foo.bar/search?q=hello` if the value in `search-field` was `hello`. Instead I get the following compilation error:

```
/index.scala.html:8: missing arguments for method search in class ReverseIndex;
 follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
     <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="get" action="@routes.Index.search">
```

Any help with why this is wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not providing default values for the query parameters in the `routes` file:

```
GET        /search        controllers.Index.search(q: String ?= "")
```

fixed the problem.